Garage door stops and returns when closing,
I changed the sensors with no improvement.  I just noticed that when the door is in the process of closing the sensor lights turn off and the door stops and returns.  When the lights remain on I move the wires to see if they go off but they remain on.
The door always opens fine and sometimes I can get it to close if I hold the close (Hard wired) button.  Any help/idea is appreciated.

Typically the cause of a garage door reversing is either something blocking the downward movement (i.e. something is blocking the occupancy sensors), or it's overloading the door mechanism due to springs not properly tensioned.  If you disconnect the opener from the door, does the door move easily in both directions and appear to be well balanced (i.e. seems well tensioned against the springs and doesn't require a huge amount of effort to either lower or raise it)?

If you have a piece of rope attached to the door so that a short person can pull it closed after releasing the chain drive, that hanging piece of rope could momentarily block the beam of the sensors, causing an immediate reversal.
Tie the rope up so that it does not dangle in the beam.

What brand is this garage door opener?
Although it does seem like a sensor issue, you may want to re-program your up-down limits. Some Genie door openers will do as you are describing when limits need to be completely reset up and then the down.
If not, there could possibly be short in a sensor wire.  Did you use the new wiring for the sensors or reuse the wiring from the old door opener?
Make sure you aren’t shorting a wire with a staple.
